# Update getmaxyx() return values (ncurse / C++)

Tags: c++, resize, ncurses

So, I'm, trying to be able to correctly resize my console window using ncurse in C++. I've been able to catch when the window is resize, the problem is that I'm not 100% sure how should I proceed after that. Let's say I have this loop in my main function (after initializing ncurse and those things...):

```
while(ch = getch())
{
        if(ch == KEY_RESIZE)
        {
            DoSometing();
        }
}
```

As I said the DoSomething in that example is called. But if I try to use ncurse's functions to get the new size of the window with

```
getmaxyx(stdscr, yMax, xMax);
```

I'm get the same values (the initial values) over and over again. I guess that's because when I do initscr(), the window size is stored somewhere and that's the value that the getmaxyx function provides. I've tried to do something like call endwin() and the again initscr() to restore those values, but that doesn't seem to work, the value that getmaxyx returns is fixed.

After searching for alternative solutions, I kind of solve the problem, using some other libraries. That's an small example, which actually works as I wanted:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ncurses.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    initscr();

    noecho();
    box(stdscr, 0, 0);

    struct winsize w;
    int ch, x, y;
    
    while(ch = getch())
    {
        if(ch == KEY_RESIZE)
        {            
            ioctl(STDOUT_FILENO, TIOCGWINSZ, &w);
            resize_term(w.ws_row, w.ws_col);
            clear();
            box(stdscr, 0, 0);
        }
        refresh();
    }

    
}
```

The thing is I'm kind of worried about portability while using this new libraries (I'm not completely sure, because I haven't started testing yet, but I understand that ncurse programs can be port to Windows).

I would really appreciate any information about how to do this in ncurse without using any other library (if it's possible), if what I'm doing now is OK or if I should be doing it in any other way. Any hint in the right direction is what I'm looking for :)

I'm using Arch Linux (kind of noobie) and qtile as a window manager. If you need any other relevant information, just ask me. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

This is causing the example to produce bogus results:

```
if(ch = KEY_RESIZE)
```

since it is always true (not a comparison, but an assignment).  The "something" is not doing anything useful, because the condition is incorrect.

Change that to

```
if(ch == KEY_RESIZE)
```

and get rid of

```
        ioctl(STDOUT_FILENO, TIOCGWINSZ, &w);
        resize_term(w.ws_row, w.ws_col);
```

Comment: Yep, my bad with the if(ch == KEY_RESIZE) error. But, getting rid of what you said doesn't solve the problem. What I want to achieve is that the main windows (stdscr) updates its size, when the user resize the terminal. The code that I provided, kind of does that, but if I remove those two lines, it won't update correctly.